# Extension on dynamic type not work in dart

Tags: dart, dynamic

I have an extension to parse from int, string,... -> to int

```
extension ParseUtilInt on dynamic {
  int? get parseInt {
    return int.tryParse(toString());
  }
}
```

```
var number = 0.parseInt; //ok: it work and can jump to define of code by ide

Map apiResponse = {'age': 24};

var age = apiResponse['age'].parseInt; //this line error and can't jump to define of 
code 

var age2 = apiResponse['age'].toString().parseInt; //ok: but not good for memory
```

The error thrown is

> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance getter 'parseInt'. Receiver: 24 Tried calling: parseInt

`apiResponse` is `Map == Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

So I think `apiResponse['age']` also is `dynamic`

What is the problem with this type?

Please help me to fix it.

thank you <